# How does a Worklight Cluster differ from a Worklight Server Farm?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Worklight Liberty Server Farm is described here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_server_farm_man_liberty.html

A Worklight Server Farm on Liberty is described here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_liberty_8_5_cluster_env.html

The first link discusses server farms.  The second link mentions a server farm, but then mentions standalone servers in a cluster.  Has IBM confused the terms cluster and farm in the second link?

What does a Farm give me over a regular set of standalone servers in a cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_server_farm_man_liberty.html is about a mandatory configuration of Worklight 6.2 so that Worklight administration operations (basically any operation performed from the administration console such as uploading a wlapp) are propagated to all instances in the farm. If that procedure is not followed the farm will behave inconsistently.

The second link (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_setting_up_WL_liberty_8_5_cluster_env.html) is about using IBM HTTP Server as a front end to all Worklight server instances. Following that procedure only is not sufficient in Worklight 6.2, to have a functional farm.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  But what features and function is the farm providing above a simple cluster?

In both cases, the WAR file must be installed on each Worklight Server.  

In both cases the WL Application is only installed once, and all instances can access the changes/updates.  Because they all share the same database.

The second link does not create a farm.  But does create a perfectly acceptable WL topology.

Is there any documentation that describes the features and function of the farm capabilities?

Thanks

Comment: What you call 'simple clusters' are not supported in Worklight 6.2. The procedure of the first link is mandatory. There is a new architecture in WL 6.2 (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_wn_wl_server_620.html) that makes this step mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Surely the second link must be updated to reflect this?

What is the limitation that prevents stand alone clusters? How does this work in the cloud given that two servers could be geographically many miles apart? 

Are there any papers explaining this?

Thanks

Comment: The link mandates that jmx must be configured for administration purposes. However nothing suggests a farm, with a farm.xml is mandatory.